# What will be behavior of already deployed tumbling window trigger?

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have a tumbling window trigger in ADF which is deployed and attached to another pipeline. This trigger is started from 2021. Now I want to attach this trigger to a new pipeline. Will this trigger create windows from 2021 for new pipeline?

Comment: Why don't you try it on some test pipeline and see the changes?